# execute javascript after css class change

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am using this code to hide a div whenever I click a button. I am trying to activate this function not on 'onclick' but whenever the button gets the class 'active'.

Is that possible?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How does this button get the class active?

Comment: What is the actual HTML Markup? If it is set up in the right way, no JavaScript is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Though, not sure how the element's class is changing, you can try calling the function if element has the class using `classList.contains()`.

The following example demonstrate that along with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block" || x.style.display === '') {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
var elem = document.getElementById("tryBtn");

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
  if(elem.classList.contains('active')){
    myFunction();
  }
});

// observe attributes
observer.observe(elem, {
  attributes: true
});

// test
setInterval(function(){
  if(elem.classList.contains('active')){
    elem.classList.remove('active');
  }
  else{
    elem.classList.add('active')
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="tryBtn">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to use the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```html
<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<button id="myButton"  onclick="changeClass()">Change class</button>
<script>
 function changeClass() {
   document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("active"); 
   console.log("Changed class to active")
 }
  
 function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   console.log(x.style.display);
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
  
const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
const config = {attributes: true};
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
       if (mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
        
            if(mutation.target.className.includes("active")){
                myFunction(); // Or you can put function code here.
            }
        }
    }
}

//Set the target node you want to observe
const targetNode = document.getElementById('myDIV');

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);


</script>
```

I used the `changeClass` function so you can see how this works. Since I suppose you already have some way of setting the class to **"active"**